# Why Can't I Use My DbContext Type?

Tags: wpf, entity-framework

I'd like to access some static properties of my DbContext type in a WPF Window. I thought I could use the same XAML that I use to refer to individual entities:

```
    <Window.Resources>
        <entity:Account x:Key="account"/> //Works fine
        <entity:MyEntities x:Key="myEntities"/> //Throws an error!
    </Window.Resources>
```

I get this error:

> No connection string named 'MyEntities' could be found in the application config file.

Why is it treating the DbContext type (MyEntities) differently than the Account entity? Is there an easy way I can access the static properties of my MyEntities type?

Comment: Sounds like you're missing a connection string for MyEntities in you WPF app.config.

Comment: The error message is pretty explicit. It appears that in your application config file, you don't have a connection string called `MyEntities`!

Comment: I actually do have a connection string (I have three!). My application runs just fine without that one line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that particular error results due to the static constructor that I placed in my DbContext. When I remove the static constructor the error changes to:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

As it turns out, the original error doesn't prevent me from compiling or running my application. I changed my code to use Scott Chamberlain's suggestion (which produces a similar ignorable error) because it is much cleaner and I can access the static properties on the DbContext just fine in spite of Visual Studio's complaints. Thanks, everyone, for the help and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you used is for creating instances, not static properties. If you want to access a static property you need to use the [`x:Static`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742135(v=vs.110).aspx) markup extension

```
<Window.Resources>
    <entity:Account x:Key="account" SomeProperty={x:Static entity:MyEntities.MyProperty}/>
</Window.Resources>
```

The above xaml would be similar to the C# code

```
var account = new Account()
{
     SomeProperty = MyEntities.MyProperty
};
this.Resources["account"] = account;
```

See that you are calling `new Account()`, if you called `new MyEntites()` (like your original example did) you get the error you where getting.

Comment: Account is an entity within the MyEntities context and so doesn't have/need a connection string. As I said in the comments section of the original question, the application connects fine and the "MyEnities" WPF line (added to simply access some static properties that I added to the DbContext type) is the only thing that generates an error.

Comment: @RandallDoser Updated answer, sorry I misunderstood.

Comment: Thanks. I like this code as I leaned something new from it, however, this actually produces a similar error. The error, however, is one of those WPF errors that does not stop the compiling/running of the application and your XAML works as intended when I do run it. I think the issue is actually one of the Static properties I created on the DbContext type which establishes my long running context. It must have to do with Visual Studio trying to resolve this property at design time and not being able to find the connection strings (for whatever reason) in the config file. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Didn't really answer my question, although your XAML code was much more elegant and the slight change in the error helped me figure out what was happening. See my posted answer...